# Convert 'NULL' to Date in SQL

Tags: sql, string, date, type-conversion

I have a column in my table called `startdate`. It is in string format. Most of the fields are 'NULL'. I am copying this column to another table which data type is 'Date'.
How can I convert all the values from string to Date in SQL.
I have tried this code:

```
INSERT INTO Destination_Table [new_date] 
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,[startdate],103) 
FROM Source_Table
```

Comment: Why don't you just set the date column to autofill with today's date (or any given date, for that matter), and just import the rows with null. Then return the date field to normal date, and import the rest? Not as shiny, but quicker than trying to find the right solution, perhaps?

Comment: Your code should work. What is the problem?

Comment: This is the error message: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Sam, in the `Source_Table`, is `NULL` the text value (4 character string, or 6 character string `'NULL'`), or is it a 0 character value `(null)` ?

Comment: Its just NULL, 4 character string

Comment: I have posted a solution that should work in negating that value.  Please bear in mind it has been some time since I worked with MSSQL, but I believe actual nulls are still passed as `null` with no quotes.  This doesn't cover edge cases like if the string has padding after, or case sensitivity - so `"NULL "` or `"   null"`  for example won't get caught.  Should be enough to get you on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using MSSQL.  If you are using MSSQL 2012, the following code should work :

```
INSERT INTO Destination_Table [new_date] 
SELECT IIF([startdate] = "NULL", null, CONVERT(DATE,[startdate],103)) 
FROM Source_Table
```

What this does, is use the `IIF()` method to check the value of `[startdate]` and if the value is the text "NULL", then return the actual `null` value which can be allowed in most fields unless you have null disabled on the `Destination_Table`.`[new_date]` field.

Since the Date field can only accept and store Date/Time/Date&Time/(actual null) information, the text "NULL" is not valid.

Following is the equivalent for MySQL

```
INSERT INTO Destination_Table [new_date] 
SELECT IF([startdate] == 'NULL', null, CONVERT(DATE,[startdate],103)) 
FROM Source_Table
```

(although I am unsure MySQL allows a conversion code as a param to `CONVERT()` )

Answer (score 1):

**nullif([startdate],'NULL')** returns [startdate] unless it equals to 'NULL' and then it returns NULL (a real NULL, not the string 'NULL')

```
INSERT INTO Destination_Table [new_date] 
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,nullif([startdate],'NULL'),103) 
from   Source_Table
```

---

For learning purposes, here are some expressions with the same results:

```
nullif(x,y)
```

---

```
case when x=y then null else x end
```

---

```
case x when y then null else x end
```

Comment: @JibinBalachandran, This is what the code deals with, therefore the NULLIF